# attempt to invoke virtual method void com.huawei.hms.rn.analytics

Tags: huawei-developers, huawei-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEcER.jpg)

Hello people, I am implementing Huawei analytics services and I have this problem, help!

I'm using import HMSAnalytics from '@hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use HMS Analytics you need to getInstance from HMS library method

`import HMSAnalytics from '@hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics';`

`await HMSAnalytics.getInstance();`
`await HMSAnalytics.onEvent(name, params);`